# I am trying to use Jolt transform for the below nested structure

Tags: json, jolt

My input JSON document looks like this;

```
{
  "inquiry": {
    "status": "",
    "moredata": "",
    "selectPurgeInd": "",
    "analysis_name": "",
    "analysis_description": "",
    "inquirytype_name": "",
    "inquirytype_description": "",
    "actiontype_name": "",
    "actiontype_description": "",
    "class_name": "",
    "class_description": "",
    "domain_name": "",
    "domain_description": "",
    "source_name": "",
    "source_descriptions": "",
    "received_name": "",
    "received_description": ""
  },
  "inquiryNbr": "",
  "openDt": "",
  "opId": "",
  "userId": "",
  "systemInd": "",
  "analysis_code": "",
  "inquirytype_code": "",
  "actiontype_code": "",
  "class_code": "",
  "domain_code": "",
  "source_code": "",
  "received_code": "",
  "customerNm": ""
}
```

I require this output format

```
{
"inquiry": {
        "status": "",
        "moredata": "",
        "selectPurgeInd": "",
        "analysis_name": "",
        "analysis_description": "",
        "inquirytype_name": "",
        "inquirytype_description": "",
        "actiontype_name": "",
        "actiontype_description": "",
        "class_name": "",
        "class_description": "",
        "domain_name": "",
        "domain_description": "",
        "source_name": "",
        "source_descriptions": "",
        "received_name": "",
        "received_description": "",
        "inquiryNbr": "",
        "openDt": "",
        "opId": "",
        "userId": "",
        "systemInd": "",
        "analysis_code": "",
        "inquirytype_code": "",
        "actiontype_code": "",
        "class_code": "",
        "domain_code": "",
        "source_code": "",
        "received_code": ""
      },
      "customerNm": ""
    }
```

The spec I used

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "inquiry": {
        "status": "",
        "moredata": "",
        "selectPurgeInd": "",
        "analysis_name": "",
        "analysis_description": "",
        "inquirytype_name": "",
        "inquirytype_description": "",
        "actiontype_name": "",
        "actiontype_description": "",
        "class_name": "",
        "class_description": "",
        "domain_name": "",
        "domain_description": "",
        "source_name": "",
        "source_descriptions": "",
        "received_name": "",
        "received_description": "",
        "inquiryNbr": "",
        "openDt": "",
        "opId": "",
        "userId": "",
        "systemInd": "",
        "analysis_code": "",
        "inquirytype_code": "",
        "actiontype_code": "",
        "class_code": "",
        "domain_code": "",
        "source_code": "",
        "received_code": ""
      },
      "customerNm": ""
    }
    }
]
```

but the output look like this;

```
{
  "inquiry" : {
    "status" : "",
    "moredata" : "",
    "selectPurgeInd" : "",
    "analysis_name" : "",
    "analysis_description" : "",
    "inquirytype_name" : "",
    "inquirytype_description" : "",
    "actiontype_name" : "",
    "actiontype_description" : "",
    "class_name" : "",
    "class_description" : "",
    "domain_name" : "",
    "domain_description" : "",
    "source_name" : "",
    "source_descriptions" : "",
    "received_name" : "",
    "received_description" : "",
    "actiontype_code" : "",
    "class_code" : "",
    "opId" : "",
    "openDt" : "",
    "received_code" : "",
    "systemInd" : "",
    "inquirytype_code" : "",
    "source_code" : "",
    "inquiryNbr" : "",
    "userId" : "",
    "domain_code" : "",
    "analysis_code" : ""
  },
  "inquiryNbr" : "",
  "openDt" : "",
  "opId" : "",
  "userId" : "",
  "systemInd" : "",
  "analysis_code" : "",
  "inquirytype_code" : "",
  "actiontype_code" : "",
  "class_code" : "",
  "domain_code" : "",
  "source_code" : "",
  "received_code" : "",
  "customerNm" : ""
}
```

Can anyone help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this spec, just shift all the values to the inquiry object.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "inquiry": {
        "*": "inquiry.&"
      },
      "*": "inquiry.&",
      "customerNm": "customerNm"
    }
  }
]
```